# How to tell typescript that an error will be thrown if an argument is null?

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following:

```
const handleParse = (arg: { value: boolean } | null) => {
    if (!arg?.value) {
        throw new Error(`\`arg\` is null`)
    }
    
    return arg.value;
}
```

Here, Typescript knows inline, that the returned `arg.value` will always be defined.

However, I'm trying to refactor the thrown error to a helper method, but it's throwing an error:

```
const checkDependency = (dependency: any) => {
    if (!dependency) {
        throw new Error(`\`dependency\` is null`)
    }
}

const handleParse = (arg: { value: boolean } | null) => {
    checkDependency(arg)
    
    return arg.value;
//         ^^^ 'arg' is possible null
}
```

How can I accomplish this? I've tried playing around with the return type, but to no avail:

```
const checkDependency = (dependency: any):  Error | void  => {
    if (!dependency) {
        throw new Error(`\`arg\` is null`)
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) for that combined with a type parameter we combine with `null`:

```typescript
function checkDependency<T>(arg: T | null): asserts arg is T {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (arg === null) {
        throw new Error(`\`arg\` is null`);
    }
}
```

Here's your example using that:

```typescript
const handleParse = (arg: { value: boolean } | null) => {
    checkDependency(arg);
    
    return arg.value; // <== No error
};
```

[Full example on the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawCJoA5pgAmhEAngDwAqAfABQCGATgOYBciViAPomCABsBASg4MAzuLRMo4xMxaIYcrgG8AUAHpNiQEhE+g4aPGTpowD1LV6zfPrEDpcESNWiALye+gkYg2OAxCgUJjgAdz40CIBRJlCmOgADAB1EhVSlOX4hROEAbntHAF91EvUIBHEoRBQGYgE0AAVmKQ8XBQ5VRAA3BgEQNA4AIzg4BrrEIp5vIWEPGj9Ch1QMHHxCEkgyVxZ8pcR9pjQoECYkBQA6Xv60PMRtRAovADk4RGl40rygA)

Type assertion functions were added in TypeScript v3.7. They're similar to [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), but they do exactly what you describe: Indicate that if the function doesn't throw, the type is as the function asserts.